# wcf Binding configuration and security

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm reading a book on Wcf. I always get confused when there is topic on binding configuration. Eg. In one chapter for securing service in internet environment, author used the following code in the config file.

```
<bindings>
 <wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="ProductsServiceWSHttpBindingConfig">
   <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
   </security>
  </binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Everything works fine as described in the book. But I don't see any description in book, why `TransportWithMessageCredential` is used in place of `Transport`. Similarly why the `<transport ...` is `None` and `<message ...` is not `None`. Is there any matrix (or any other way to figure out) about which options to use with which binding (and in which environment)? My hunch is that certain options will go with certain binding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, here's a few:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx

http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/03/31/wcf-binding-decision.aspx

http://architectopia.blogspot.com/2008/01/wcf-binding-decision-chart.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already been answered however heres are some thoughts for those who are looking for quick answer.

TransportWithMessageCredential is basically saying that the transmission is over https (secure) and the username and password will be in security header.

"Client authentication is performed by putting the client credential directly in the message. This allows you to use any credential type that is supported by the message security mode for the client authentication while keeping the performance benefit of transport security mode."
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354508.aspx